# Determining which cpus are under scheduler's supervision in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

After learning that one could isolate cpus (in a sense that they are no more under the supervision of scheduler) using isolcpus parameter at boot time; how one can determine what cpus are under the supervision in linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try [stress](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/), it will try to consume all the cpu resources in linux. then with 'top' command, you can see which cpu is isolated.